# How to generate protobuf in scala?

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

Here is what my proto file looks like :

```
option java_package = "com.test.report";

message ClientRecord
 {
optional string cust_id           = 1;
optional double tx_bytes          = 2;
optional double rx_bytes          = 3;
optional string source_id         = 4;
optional string dest_id           = 5;
}

message ClientRecords
{
repeated ClientRecord record       = 1;
}
```

I am able to write protobuf generator/decoder in python, but how do I write it in Scala/Java. Can anyone help me to write a generator in Scala for my example?

Comment: protoc can generate classes from Java.

Comment: Take a look at this project: [ScalaBuff](https://github.com/SandroGrzicic/ScalaBuff) is a compiler of Scala Protocol Buffers (protobuf)

Comment: I am going to write a proto in scala but I don't understand what are the numbers you added? why we don't leave the values empty?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [ScalaPB](http://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/)

More specifically, check out [this section](http://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/generated-code.html) which shows an example of how generate a Scala case class for a given proto file. It will generate parsers and serializers as well. Hope this helps you